# buildroot and rpi-firmware

Tags: kernel, driver

I am able to bring up a minimal kernel using raspberrypi_defconfig in buildroot. I noticed that there are some .ko files in the rpi-firmware package downloaded from git. How can I include those into the kernel from buildroot for peripheral support?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out.
 I just have to enable the required drivers from the linux configuration menu (`make linux-menuconfig`) .

If I enable them as modules, they will be copied into a folder in /lib. Otherwise, they will be integrated in the zImage